# React native app firebase.auth() not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a react native app on development that uses a firebase authentication. it was working fine until yesterday.  I used the following command to build the app yesterday

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res
>
> gradlew assembleRelease

After that, not the created apk or the source code is not working when trying to log in. it is showing that firebase.auth() is not a function. here is my code

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Restaurent')
  if(user){
    //--------------------------Async Test--------------------------
     AsyncStorage.setItem("user", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
     console.log("AsyncStorage= "+ asyncValue)
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
  }else{

  }
}
```

Comment: Did any of your dependencies change since the last time you succfessfully built the app with `gradlew`? And did you update/link any of the files in the `/android` folder, like adding third-party modules or native configuration in the `AndroidManifest.xml` or `build.gradle` files?

Comment: @MarcelKalveram no